# Как передавать изменяемые переменные между файлами python

Tags: python, парсер, aiogram

учусь писать парсера с телеграм ботом на aiogram в двух разных файлах , с парсером вроде все получилось как и телеграм ботом , но возникла проблема мне бы хотелось вписывать значения в тг и после этого эти значения передавал в парсер (такие значения как цена , название предмета ),
я пробовал через сохранение в txt файл , но как то не очень , так - же пробовал на прямую пишет файл цикличный.
код тг бота

```
from aiogram import Bot , Dispatcher ,  executor ,  types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold , hlink
from config import TOKEN
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import json
from normal_price import data_colected , curryncy 
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State , StatesGroup

    bot = Bot(TOKEN ,parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML  )
dp= Dispatcher(bot , storage=MemoryStorage())


class fsm_serch(StatesGroup):
    price_from = State()
    price_to = State()




@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message:types.Message):
    start_buttons = ['Начать поиск', 'Поиск предмета', 'Задать параметры цены поиска' ]
    keyboard= types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*start_buttons)
    await message.answer('пик', reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Начать поиск'))
async def get_sale(message:types.Message):
    await message.answer('Wait.....'+'\n'
    "Выбрано поиск по выгоде"+'\n' 'Примерное время сбора информации 10 минут')
    data_colected()

    await message.answer('Почти готово'+'\n'
    "Уже все..."
    )

    with open('result.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    for index ,item in enumerate(data):
        card = card = f'{hlink(item.get("full_name"), item.get("img"))}\n' \
            f'{hbold("Качество:  ")}{item.get("full_float")}\n ' \
            f'{hbold("Прайс:  ")}{item.get("full_price")} {item.get ("full_currency") } \n ' \
            f'{hbold("Прайс стим:  ")}{item.get("steam_price")} {item.get ("full_currency") } \n ' \
            f'{hbold("Выгода:  ")}{item.get("benefit")} {item.get ("full_currency") }\n ' \
            f'{hlink(("Ссылка стим  "), item.get("steam_url"))}\n ' \
            f'{hlink(("Ссылка маркета  ") , item.get("url"))}\n ' \
            f'{hlink(("Wiki CSGO  "), item.get("Wiki money"))}\n '

        if index%20==0:
            print("Пауза")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("1")
            print("2")
            print("3")
        await message.answer(card)
    print("Конец")
    await message.answer("Конец.")

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Задать параметры цены поиска'),state=None)
async def Set_Price(message:types.Message):
    price_data.clear()
    await fsm_serch.price_from.set()
    await message.answer('Введите ОТ какой цены искать вещи.')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=fsm_serch.price_from)
async def price_from(message:types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global price_frome
    price_frome = message.text
    if price_frome.isdigit() is True:
        await fsm_serch.next()
        await message.answer('Введите ДО какой цены искать вещи.')
    else :
       await message.answer('Ведены недопустимые значения, попробуйте еще раз.')
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'], state=fsm_serch.price_to)
async def price_to(message:types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global price_too
    price_too = message.text
    if price_too.isdigit() is True:
        if int(price_frome) < int(price_too):
            await message.answer('Записал нужные значения.')
            price_data.append({
                                        "price_frome": price_frome,
                                        "price_too": price_too
                               })

            with open('options.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
                json.dump(price_data, file, indent=4 , ensure_ascii=False)

            start_buttons = ['По выгоде', 'Поиск предмета', 'Задать параметры цены поиска' ]
            keyboard= types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            keyboard.add(*start_buttons)
            await message.answer('пик', reply_markup=keyboard)


            await state.finish()
        else :
            await message.answer('Ведены недопустимые значения.')  
    else :
       await message.answer('Ведены недопустимые значения, попробуйте еще раз.')  
    
def main():
    print("Бот запущен")
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp)
    except Exception as e:
        print('таймаут') 
        time.sleep(15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

код парсера

```
    from email import header
from glob import glob
import json
from pickle import TRUE
import random
from unittest import skip
from urllib import response
from weakref import proxy
from wsgiref.headers import Headers
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import lxml
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util import Retry
import re
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool


random_time = random.uniform(3, 5)
print (random_time)

ban_time = 235

ua = UserAgent()
result  = []


try :
    with open('options.json') as file:
        open_price = json.load(file)
        for pricess in open_price:
            prices1 = prices1 = pricess.get("price_frome")
            prices2 = prices2 = pricess.get("price_too")
            price_on = prices1
        price_off = prices2
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            price_on = "50"
            price_off = "1000"



curryncy = 'rub'
if curryncy == 'rub':
    curryncy_steam = 5
elif curryncy == 'usd':
    curryncy_steam = 1


search = ''
proxies = {

    'http' : 'http://45.8.115.155:81'
}




price_difference  = 1.15

page_number = 3



base_url = 'https://market.csgo.com'



sesi= Session()



s = Session()


s.headers.update({'User-Agent': ua.random,})

s.cookies.setdefault('_language', 'en')

s.get(base_url +'/currency/switch/' +curryncy)



def data_colected():          
        result.clear()
        print("Произведена отчистка.")
        for pages in range(1 , page_number + 1 , 1 ):
            pages = str(pages)
            print ( "Страница под номером" +"  " + pages )
            url = '?t=&t=all&p='+pages+'&rs='+price_on+';'+price_off+'&search='+search+'&sd=desc'
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1 , 3))
            response = s.get(good_url :=  base_url + url)
            print (response) 
            print (good_url)   
            soup= bs(response.text, "lxml")
            all_links = soup.find_all('a' , class_='item hot')
            if all_links == []:
                print('неверно')
            else:
                for link in all_links:
                    url1 = 'https://market.csgo.com' + link['href']
                    print(url1)
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1 , 1.5))
                    responses = s.get(url1)
                    soup= bs(responses.text, "lxml")
                    try :
                        full_name = soup.find('div', class_='item-h1').find('h1').get_text(strip=True)
                        full_float = soup.find('div', class_='item-h1').find('span').get_text(strip=True)
                        full_price= soup.find('div', class_='ip-bestprice').__str__().replace('<div class="ip-bestprice">', '').replace('<small></small>', '').replace('</div>', '').replace('<small class="USD"></small>', '').strip()
                        full_price = full_price.replace(' ','')
                        if full_price == 'None':
                            full_price = 1
                        full_price =  float( full_price )
                        full_currency = soup.find('div', class_=['currency-selector__item', 'active']).get_text(strip=True)
                        img = soup.find('div',class_='ip-pic')
                        img = img.findChildren('img')[0]                            
                        imge = img['src']
                        full_name= full_name.__str__().replace('|', '')
                    except AttributeError:
                        print('не получилось найти')
                        continue
#вики
                    steam_name =full_name.__str__().lower().replace('  ','/').replace(' ','-')
                    steam_float = "weapon"
                    if steam_float == "Container":
                        items = "cases"
                    if steam_float == "Agent":
                        steam_name = steam_name.__str__().lower().replace('  ','/').replace(' ','-').replace('.','').replace('/','-')
                        items = "agents"
                    if steam_float == "knife":
                        items = "knife"
                    if steam_float == "weapon":
                        items = "weapons"
                    wiki_money = "https://wiki.cs.money/ru/"+ items +"/"+steam_name
                    wiki_responses = requests.get(wiki_money)
                    if wiki_responses.status_code == 200:
                        wiki_url = wiki_money

                    else:
                        wiki_url = "Отсуствует"

#стим
                    steam_name = full_name.__str__().replace(' (Factory New)', '').replace(' (Minimal Wear)', '').replace(' (Field-Tested)', '').replace(' (Well-Worn)', '').replace(' (Battle-Scarred)', '')
                    steam_name = steam_name.__str__().replace('StatTrak™ ', 'StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20').replace("'", '%27').replace("  ", '%20%7C%20').replace(" ", '%20')
                    steam_float = full_float.__str__().replace('Прямо с завода', 'Factory New').replace('Немного поношенное', 'Minimal Wear').replace('После полевых испытаний', 'Field-Tested').replace('Поношенное', 'Well-Worn').replace('Закалённое в боях', 'Battle-Scarred').replace('Контейнер', 'Container').replace(' ', '%20')
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1 , 3.5))
                    NMURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name="+steam_name+"%20%28"+steam_float+"%29&appid=730&currency="+str(curryncy_steam)
                    if steam_float == "Container":
                        steam_float = ''.__str__()
                        NMURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name="+steam_name+steam_float+"&appid=730&currency="+str(curryncy_steam)
                    if steam_float == "Sticker":
                        steam_float = ''.__str__()
                        NMURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name="+steam_name+steam_float+"&appid=730&currency="+str(curryncy_steam)
                    if steam_float == "Agent":
                        steam_float = ''.__str__()
                        NMURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name="+steam_name+steam_float+"&appid=730&currency="+str(curryncy_steam)
                    if steam_float == "Music Kit":
                        steam_float = ''.__str__()
                        NMURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name="+steam_name+steam_float+"&appid=730&currency="+str(curryncy_steam)

                    steam_name = full_name.__str__().replace(' ', '+').replace('StatTrak™', '%22StatTrak%E2%84%A2+')   
                    steam_float = full_float.__str__().replace('Поношенное', '').replace('Прямо с завода', '').replace('После полевых испытаний', ' ').replace('Закалённое в боях', ' ').replace('Немного поношенное', ' ').replace(' ', '+')
                    url_steam ="https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q="+steam_name+"+"+steam_float
                    data = sesi.get(NMURL).json()
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1 , 3))
                    try :
                        steam_price = data.get("lowest_price")
                        if steam_price == None:
                            steam_price = data.get("median_price")
                            if steam_price == None:
                                steam_price = 1
                                print("бан")
                                time.sleep(random.uniform(20 , 25))
                        
                        steam_price = steam_price.__str__().replace(' pуб.','').replace(',','.').replace(' ','')
                    except AttributeError :
                        print("Неполучилось собрать")
                        steam_price = 1





                    price1 =  int(float(full_price))
                    price2 =  int(float(steam_price))

#отбор результатов

                    benefit= price2 - price1
                    benefit= str(benefit)
                    if  price1 * price_difference <= price2 or price2 == 1 :
                        print("добавляем")
                        result.append(

                                    {
                                        "img": imge,
                                        "full_name": full_name,
                                        "full_float": full_float,
                                        'full_price': full_price,
                                        'steam_price': steam_price,
                                        'benefit': benefit,
                                        'full_currency': full_currency,
                                        'url': url1,
                                        'steam_url': url_steam,
                                        'Wiki money' : wiki_url

                                    }
                                )

            with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
                json.dump(result, file, indent=4 , ensure_ascii=False)
            print(len(result))


def data_steam():
        steam_name = "SG 553  Cyrex".__str__().lower().replace('  ','/').replace(' ','-')
        steam_float = "weapon"
        if steam_float == "Container":
            items = "cases"
        if steam_float == "Agent":
            steam_name = steam_name.__str__().lower().replace('  ','/').replace(' ','-').replace('.','').replace('/','-')
            items = "agents"
        if steam_float == "knife":
            items = "knife"
        if steam_float == "weapon":
            items = "weapons"
        wiki_money = "https://wiki.cs.money/ru/"+ items +"/"+steam_name
        wiki_responses = requests.get(wiki_money)
        if wiki_responses.status_code == 200:
            print(wiki_money)
                                                                      
                
def main():
    data_colected()
    #data_steam()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Прошу прощения за столь грязный код.

Comment: Здравствуйте, забыл в посте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечая на задачу, описанную в комментарии, можно сделать вот так (врать не буду, решение не самое оптимальное, но лучше чем дозапись и чтение с текстового файла).
Для этого создал один дополнительный файл для переменных и еще один файл для запуска всех функций. Создал глобальные переменные для большего вашего удобства при работе с асинхронными функциями:

**parcer**

```
import helper

def parcing():
    global result
    result = helper.price
```

**telegram**

```
import parcer
def input_info():
    global data
    data = input()

def output():
    output_price = parcer.result
    print(output_price)
```

**helper**

```
import telegram

def start():
    global price
    telegram.input_info()
    price = telegram.data
```

****launcher****

```
import parcer
import telegram
import helper

main.start()
Test.parcing()
run.output()
```

Comment: Cпасибо еще раз , вроде работает , теперь буду думать как правильно импортировать в мой проект.

Comment: И еще возник вопрос обязательно ли использовать лаунчер для запуска программ ?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно. Но часто когда есть какой то основной файл, это улучшает структуру и делает код более простым к понимаю, если у вас большой проект с большим количеством модулей и файлов. Но, конечно вы можете запихнуть часть лаунчера в какой то из файлов и запускать этот файл. Решение запускать вручную (через несколько командных строк) параллельно несколько файлов - нехорошее, в таком случае лучше использовать асинхронные функции и запускать их в параллельных потоках

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ .

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял суть вопроса, однако если задача стоит в обмене переменными между двумя файлами - файлами бота и парсера, то можно импортировать в файл бота файл парсера, и вызывать в файле бота какие-либо функции из файла парсера. Точно так же и с переменными, просто перед выполняемым действием или вызываемым объектом используй синтаксис file.variable или file.func(), где file - файл file.py который импортируется, а variable и func() - это переменная и функция соответственно. Пример:

Файл Test.py:

```
Hello = 'world!'
def setup_value(a):
    b = a + 2
    return b
```

Файл Main.py (который и запускается):

```
import Test

print(Test.setup_value(3)) #запуск функции которая описана в test.py

print(Test.Hello) #получение переменной которая задается в test.py
```

Результат:

```
5
world!
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ , попробую

Comment: я хотел сделать бота в котором можно было выбрать (цену и другие параметры для парсера) , что-бы можно было вписывать в телеграме параметры и они передавались парсеру, но т.к бот телеграма импортирует функции из парсера получается то он цикличный , я пробовал через 3й файл и импорт засовывал в функцию , но не работает, а сейчас у меня так и работает через txt файл , но хотелось бы реализовать по другому.